# How to insert MasterDetailsBlock into View (ViewPart)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Usually Master details block inserted into Formpage like following code.

```java
    public class UnitConfigurationEditorPage extends FormPage {  

        @Override
        Protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) {
          FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
          form = managedForm.getForm();
          form.setText("Unit Configuration");

          unitConfigurationMasterDetailsBlock = new UnitConfigurationMasterDetailsBlock(this,prepMasterProject);

          unitConfigurationMasterDetailsBlock.createContent(managedForm);
        }
   }
```

But I'm not expecting editor, I want to show as a view. So I want to add MasterDetailsBlock into View(ViewPart) instead of FormPage.

I have tried following code but I have received this error.

```
  Error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ScrolledForm cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.forms.IManagedForm"
```

```java
  public class MasterBlockView extends ViewPart {
        @Override
        public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

            Composite composite = formToolkit.createComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            formToolkit.paintBordersFor(composite);
            composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

            ScrolledForm scrldfrmNewScrolledform = formToolkit.createScrolledForm(composite);
            scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
            formToolkit.paintBordersFor(scrldfrmNewScrolledform);
            scrldfrmNewScrolledform.setText("New ScrolledForm");        

            JobMasterDetailsBlock jobMasterDetailsBlock = new JobMasterDetailsBlock(this);
            jobMasterDetailsBlock.createContent((IManagedForm) scrldfrmNewScrolledform);
       }        
  }
```

Please help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. `FormPage` expects to be part of a `FormEditor` or at least be contained in something implementing `IManagedForm`. The only existing implementation of `IManagedForm` is in the form editor code.

Comment: Can you please guide me to show master details page as like viewer?